# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using sqlite LIKE clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to extract a list of events from sqlite database.
Here is the method that I use

```
public List<Event> printMonths(String eventId, String date) {
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT eventName, date FROM events WHERE eventId = ? AND date LIKE ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{eventId, "%" + date});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                Event event = new Event();
                event.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                event.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                events.add(event);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return events;
}
```

Returns an error

    `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)`

If I exclude the LIKE clause everything works fine.

Why I'm getting this error and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you have like as array instead of a string?

Comment: use while loop instead of do while

Comment: Your stack trace does not appear to match your code. For example, you are not calling `get()` anywhere.

Comment: I think your cursor return null when you apply LIKE

Comment: @CommonsWare I simplified the original code for this questions. The code does work without LIKE clause and returns the desired list. I don't understand why this clause breaks the code execution with an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: In the future, your [mcve] should include the full Java stack trace (not a few lines), plus your code that is referenced in that stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
public List<Event> printMonths(String eventId, String date) {
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT eventName, date FROM events WHERE eventId = ? AND date LIKE ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{eventId, "%" + date});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
            Event event = new Event();
            event.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            event.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            events.add(event);
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
    db.close();
    return events;
}
```

Comment: @sfirc Check your arraylist size in printMonths() method and in Adapter class

Comment: Oh man! You're right! I forgot to change the returning value from getItemCount() in Adapter class. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sfirc Welcome bro

Comment: This code will skip the first row, consider using do-while instead.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me good :

```
    String query= "SELECT " +columnName+ " FROM " + tableName+ " WHERE " + "eventId= " + eventiD+ " AND date LIKE = " + yourTargetDate

 try {

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

       // Your code enter here 
       // example : event.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Name)))

            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
        sqlDB.close();
    }

    return events;
```